# The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application

Tags: iis-7

Hi any one can help me for IIS 7 access.

we are getting following failed message while accessing our url.

1. -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS

ModuleName
IIS Web Core

Notification 1

HttpStatus 500

HttpReason Internal Server Error

HttpSubStatus 0

ErrorCode 2147943395

ConfigExceptionInfo

Notification BEGIN_REQUEST ErrorCode

The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (0x800703e3)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an issue on the server where IIS runs. You have to set the proper .NET version in the application pool in IIS7, also check if you need to run the application pool in 32-bit mode. Further more you need to set the proper rights on the application pool for the application pool identity (in most cases NetworkService). If you application is running in SSL mode make sure you have this configured in the web.config.